Why the cyclic subgroup generated by an element is a well-defined set
Let $G$ be a group and $a\in G$. We define the cyclic subgroup generated by $a$ as
$$
\langle a\rangle = \{a^n: n\in\mathbb{Z}\}.
$$
If I haven't learned the classification of cyclic groups, to me repetitive elements might appear irregularly in this collection. However, a set is defined to be an unambiguous collection of distinct elements. I don't know how to justify that this is a set.
Some people said that this is the set after removing all repetitive elements. But removing elements sounds like a manual procedure to me which is hard to do on an infinite set.
This is probably a very basic question. I don't know why I suddenly have this question when reviewing group theory.
Any help is welcome!

Two sets are equal if they have the same elements.
So, ${x,x} = {x}$ and there is nothing wrong with this.

It is typical to have such possible duplicates inside the brackets. Compare e.g. to the set of rationals ${  a/b \mid a,b \in \mathbb{Z}, b \neq 0      }$

If you prefer, you could also define $\langle a\rangle = {x \in G,\vert,\exists n \in \mathbb{Z}: x = a^n}$.

"a set is defined to be an unambiguous collection of distinct elements" No. A set is defined by the axioms of whatever set theory you're working in. For example, in ZF, $\langle a \rangle$ is given by the axiom of replacement.

A set is a collection of distinct objects, however we do not require when we define the sets, all the elements satisfying the requirement is unique. For example, $A={x:x^2=1\land(x+1)=2}$ is a okay  definition to say $A={1}$.

@NaïmFavier I think you are making a point. I might should take some time to learn ZFC since the definition of a set in the Naive Set Theory seems too ambiguous for me sometimes.

@TobErnack Oh yeah then it is a set because $G$ is a set and $a\in G$ is either in this subgroup or not.

@Slugger Sure... But why are sets with duplicate elements sets? How to think about them?

Sets cannot have multiple elements. ${a, a}$ and ${a}$ denote the same set: the singleton set containing $a$.

Assuming that the domain of a function is a set, it's image is also a set. This (roughly speaking) is one of the axioms of set theory, known as the axiom of replacement. It does not matter whether the function is one-to-one.
For example here is a familiar set:
$$\{x^2 \mid x \in \mathbb R\}
$$
This set is equal to $[0,\infty)$, because it is the image of the function $f(x)=x^2$ defined on $\mathbb R$. It does not matter that $f$ is not a one-to-one function: even though the element $4 \in [0,\infty)$ is represented both as $f(2)$ and as $f(-2)$, it's still just one thing, namely the number $4$.
The same is going on with cyclic groups. For a cyclic group $G$ of order $3$ generated by an element $a$, it does not matter that the function $f : \mathbb Z \to G$ defined by $f(n)=a^n$ is not a one-to-one function; even though $a$ is represented both as $f(1) = a^1$ and as $f(4)=a^4$, it's still just one thing, namely the group element $a$.

It seems that this axiom of replacement explains why some sets with duplicate elements are sets. I might should take some time to read about ZFC.

One thing to keep in mind: there is no concept in set theory of "duplicate elements". In my example of $4 = f(2) = f(-2)$, you might, if you wish to, call that a "duplicate element", but you should keep in mind that just about every mathematical object has infinitely many different descriptions. My wife keeps a piece of paper with her son's childhood inspiration: $1 = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{4} = \frac{1}{8} + \frac{1}{8} + \frac{1}{8} + \frac{1}{8} + \frac{1}{8} + \frac{1}{8} + \frac{1}{8} + \frac{1}{8} = ...$.
